# Преобразование списка

Tags: python, list

Как преобразовать `a = [[15530], [15531], [15537], [15534]]` в `b = [15530, 15531, 15537, 15534]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо взять первый элемент каждого списка

```
b = [el[0] for el in a]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
b = []
a = [[15530], [15531], [15537], [15534]]
for i in a:
    b.append(i[0])

print(b)
# b = [15530, 15531, 15537, 15534]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно гораздо проще

```
b = sum(a, [])
```